# Creating Project from existing source code in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse. Working on school project from source code provided by instructor. Project compiles without problems using provided `makefile`, but I want to compile/edit inside of Eclipse.

I have tried to import as Makefile project, but right away getting an error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.
```

Here is a basic list of files.
Main:

```
Makefile 
mm.{c,h} 
malloc.c
mdriver.c 
short{1,2}-bal.rep
```

Supporting:

```
config.h 
fsecs.{c,h} 
clock.{c,h} 
fcyc.{c,h} 
ftimer.{c,h} 
memlib.{c,h}
```

Why I can't simply "Import" source, as I can do it in Visual Studio ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDT will attempt to build the project using `make all`, and it seems that your `Makefile` does not have that target. Easiest is to add:

```
all: your-target-to-make-stuff
```

to your `Makefile`. If you want to configure how CDT invokes make, you can right-click on the project, select *Properties → C/C++ Build*. Under the *Behavior* tab, you can select which make targets CDT should invoke when building and cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Eclipse with C/C++ plugin at my hands right now, but I have an idea what it could be:

It appears that your Eclipse is starting make with the specific target 'all', which doesn't seem to exist in the Makefile - you should be able to reproduce this behavior on the command line with the command `make all` instead of just `make`.

If this is the case, there are two solutions: one is to modify the Makefile to introduce a target 'all'; or modify the C/C++ builder settings in Eclipse to execute the make without any argument.

Comment: If this is the case (I too don't have the plugin handy) then user should be able to edit the Run Configuration instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the C/C++ for developers plugin.
Or in many cases I would use Ant to create or call make files.

Comment: I have this plug-in installed. But no luck